# Correct way to run tensorflow function or any function using map on tf dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Below is the data augmentation function that I created.

```
import tensorFlow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa    

def augment_data(ds):
    
    seed = tf.random.Generator.from_seed(1).normal([])
    seed_2d = (1, 2)

    # flipped images
    ds_flipped = ds.map(lambda img, lbl: (tf.image.flip_left_right(img), lbl))
    # induce random brightness
    ds_rnb = ds.map(lambda img, lbl : 
                    (tf.image.stateless_random_brightness(img, 
                                                          max_delta=0.65, 
                                                          seed=seed_2d), 
                    lbl))
    print('ds_flipped, ds_rnb ran successfully')
    # centre crop
    ds_cc = ds.map(lambda img, lbl:
                        (tf.image.central_crop(img, 
                                               central_fraction=0.8), 
                        lbl))
    
    ds_ran_zoom = ds.map(lambda img, lbl:
                        (tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(img, 
                                                              zoom_range=(.30, .70)),
                        lbl))
    

    return ds_flipped, ds_rnb, ds_cc, ds_ran_zoom
```

The functions for flipped images and random brightness are working fine but **tf.image.central_crop** and **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom** are not working.

Calling **augment_data(ds)** gives the following error

1. Running **tf.image.central_crop** giving me an error:

> ValueError: `image` should either be a Tensor with rank = 3 or
> rank = 4. Had rank = None.

2. Running **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom** giving me an error

> in transform_matrix_offset_center  *
> o_x = float(x) / 2 + 0.5
>
> ```
> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
> ```

But if I run the central_crop function without using the map then the below code works fine

```
for image, label in train_data:
  _ = tf.image.central_crop(image, central_fraction=0.8)
  
print('tf.image.central_crop ran successfully')
```

outputs

> tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom ran successfully

If we run **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random.zoom** in the same way then we get the error

```
for image, label in train_data:
  _ = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(image, zoom_range=(.30, .70))
```

> RuntimeError: affine matrix has wrong number of rows

Where  in order to run **tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random.zoom** requires un-batching of the dataset. So the below code works fine

```
for image, label in train_data.unbatch().take(1):
  _ = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom(image, zoom_range=(.30, .70))

print('tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom ran successfully')
```

I have created a [google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_UVLXAViJcYyO0WmOBDLbzoPre9lSz3G#scrollTo=onBx5hrBrScf) to replicate the issue.

1. What is the best way to run the TensorFlow function using the map function on the tf dataset?
2. What is the way to know whether any function is able to run on tf dataset using map function?
3. How to create a function that runs on batched and un-batched dataset both?

As you see above most of the functions are able to run on a single image but when it comes to running them using a map, different functions are throwing different errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the shape of the images and labels is unknown. You should use `set_shape` at the end of the `read_tfrecord` function : `decoded_image.set_shape(img_x, img_y, channels)` and also for the label.

1. If you set the image and label shape in the dataset, most Tensorflow functions will work by applying map, both batched and unbatched.
2. tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_zoom has a problem because it only takes a 3D Tensorflow tensor as an input and outputs a numpy array. This particular transformation is problematic.